# Get the progress of list iteration as a integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am writing a python application where i have two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3]
```

I am iterating `b` list over `a` list and I want to get the progress of the process in percentage:

```
for a_element in a:
    b_index = 1
    for b_element in b:
        progress = ((b_index/len(b)) / len(a)) * 100
        b_index = b_index + 1
        print(int(progress))
```

But this isn't giving the right progress. Does anyone know how to calculate correct progress in this kind of scenario?

I want to know the overall progress of the process.

Comment: To start, your nested for-loop has a total of `len(a) * len(b)` iterations, not `len(a)` iterations. Then, simply initialize a counter = 0 outside the outer loop, and increment it inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3]

total_count = len(a) * len(b)
count  = 0

for a_element in a:
    for b_element in b:
        count += 1
        progress = (count / total_count) * 100
        print(int(progress))
```

You just count how far you are and divide that by the precalculated total.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3]

for i in range(1, len(a)+1):
    for j in range (1, len(b)+1):
        progress = j/len(b) *i / len(a)  * 100
        print(int(progress))

#another
a_index = 1
for a_element in a:    
    b_index = 1
    for b_element in b:
        progress = b_index/len(b) * a_index/len(a)  * 100
        print(int(progress))
        b_index += 1
    a_index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? 100% divided by all iterations happening (len(a)*len(b)), which is 12 in this case. So one iteration is 8,33%. You multiply that with b_index and you got your progress in percentage. :)

```
progress = ((100.0/(len(a)*len(b)))*b_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use enumerate to index:

```
for i, a_element in enumerate(a):
    for j, b_element in enumerate(b):
        progress = (((j+1)/len(b)+i)/len(a)) * 100
        print(int(progress))
```

output for your sample input:

```
8
16
25
33
41
50
58
66
75
83
91
100
```